# Gitlab-CI : ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, gitlab-ci

#### *ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)*

Hi guys !
I have a little (big) issue with my gitlab-ci.yml :(

I'm trying to run my tests PHPUnit on the pipeline but when I want to create a mysql database and to connect it, it fails.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: jakzal/phpqa:php8.0

before_script:
        - composer install
                
stages: 
    - SecurityChecker
    - UnitTests

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - ~/.composer/cache/files    

#On teste qu'il n'y a pas de faille de sécurité dans les différentes librairies
security-checker:
    stage: SecurityChecker
    script:
        - local-php-security-checker composer.lock
    allow_failure: false

#On lance les tests unitaires PHP UNIT    
phpunit:
    stage: UnitTests
    services:
        - name: mysql:latest
    before_script:
        - apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev autoconf build-essential pkg-config libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev default-mysql-client mariadb-client mariadb-server
        - curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
        - docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip
        # Connect MySQL
        - echo "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');" | mysql -u root
        - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h mysql "$MYSQL_DATABASE"
        # Import BDD tests
        - mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h localhost < "database.sql"
    script:
        - vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox
    allow_failure: false
```

This is the result :

[Pipeline error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeL7G.png)

Do you have any ideas fo my issue ?
I didn't found anything on the different forums for now... :sleepy:

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my issue is this code !
It works for me :)

```
#On lance les tests unitaires PHP UNIT    
phpunit:
    stage: UnitTests
    services:
        - name: mysql:8.0.11
    variables: 
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database-name' 
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        DB_USERNAME: 'runner'
        DB_PASSWORD: 'password'
        DB_HOST: 'mysql'  
    before_script:
        # Install packages and docker
        - apt-get update -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev autoconf curl libmcrypt-dev build-essential pkg-config libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev default-mysql-client mariadb-client mariadb-server
        - docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip
        # Config MySQL
        - rm -f /tmp/mysql.sock.lock
        - sleep 10 
        # Import BDD for tests units
        - mysql -u root -h "$DB_HOST" < "web/files/database-test.sql"
        # Check BDD
        - echo "SHOW tables;" | mysql -u root -h "$DB_HOST" -D "$MYSQL_DATABASE"
    script:
        - vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox
    allow_failure: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/ 
I was able to get it work like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

services:
  - mariadb

test:
  stage: test
  image: mariadb
  variables:
    MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    MARIADB_DATABASE: dbname
  script:
    - mysql --user=root --password="$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb
```

Might you have to change `-h localhost` to `-h mysql`.